# Hokuyo_node tutorial error

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I followed the exact steps on http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node/Tutorials/UsingTheHokuyoNode

Everything showed up as expected until I reached the final step, which is
rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find hokuyo_node`/hokuyo_test.vcg

I got an error:
ERROR: the config file '/opt/ros/indigo/share/hokuyo_node/hokuyo_test.vcg' is a .vcg file, which is the old rviz config format.
New config files have a .rviz extension and use YAML formatting.  The format changed
between Fuerte and Groovy.  There is not (yet) an automated conversion program.

I tried to change the command to rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find hokuyo_node`/hokuyo_test.rviz, rviz did launch, but I just could not change the fixed frame to '/laser' in the global options, the fixed frame is 'map' when rviz launched.

Can anyone please give me some advice?

Thanks.
Steven

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208820/hokuyo_node-tutorial-error/) by [StevenJiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/22272/stevenjiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-05-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sergiocruz86](https://answers.ros.org/users/22674/sergiocruz86/) on 2015-06-05**:
Hi, Steven. I'm on the same boat as you are! Did you get the solution? Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Run rviz without the .vcg file i.e. rosrun rviz rviz. Set Global Options -> Fixed frame = /laser and Grid -> Reference Frame = /laser. The Add -> LaserScan, and set it's topic to /scan. You should see the laser scan on the grid.

---

Originally posted by [rj](https://answers.ros.org/users/24358/rj/) with karma: 46 on 2015-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-10-08**:
Just to elaborate on this: the Fixed Frame field is also a text entry field; you may have to manually type in '/laser'

**Comment by [BoY](https://answers.ros.org/users/29954/boy/) on 2017-04-06**:
Thanks! Got the data successfully shown on the rviz!